# Using WHERE NOT IN CLAUSE in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following query. Could you please tell me how to implement it in codeigniter.

```
SELECT mnu_name,mnu_desc,mnu_type FROM central_web_auth_mnu 
  WHERE mnu_name NOT IN(
      SELECT mnu_name FROM central_web_auth_grp_mnu WHERE  gr_id='.$grp.'
  ) ORDER BY mnu_desc;
```

Thank You.

Comment: If your CI version is 2 you can follow the answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
 $this->db->select('mnu_name, mnu_desc, mnu_type')->where('`mnu_name` NOT IN (SELECT `mnu_name` FROM `central_web_auth_grp_mnu` WHERE idgr_id= $grp)', NULL, FALSE)->order_by('mnu_desc', 'desc')->get('central_web_auth_mnu');
```

set false as third parameter so that escaping will skip:

Answer (score 3):

`CI` active db library does support array params in `where_in()` or `where_not_in()` methods, so you can use `where()` method and pass condition as string, try this query

```
$this->db->select('mnu_name, mnu_desc, mnu_type')
->where('mnu_name NOT IN(SELECT mnu_name FROM central_web_auth_grp_mnu WHERE gr_id='.$grp.')')
->order_by('mnu_desc', 'desc')
->get('central_web_auth_mnu')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use codeigniter's Active Record library to achieve this (thanks Girish)

```
$this->db->select('mnu_name, mnu_desc, mnu_type')
->where('mnu_name NOT IN(SELECT mnu_name FROM central_web_auth_grp_mnu WHERE gr_id='.$grp.')')
->order_by('mnu_desc', 'desc');

$query = $this->db->get();
$num_rows = $query->num_rows();
```